# In cygwin how do I check the file format of a file, how do I change the format from dos to unix?

Tags: unix, cygwin, dos

In cygwin how do I check the file format of a file, how do I change the format from dos to unix?

This question has probably already been answered before, but I could not find the answer in previous posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cygutils` package has `dos2unix` and other such utilities. See [this link](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html) for more details. Specifically:

> One of the hassles of Unix-Windows
>   interoperability is the different line
>   endings on text files. As mentioned in
>   the section called “Text and Binary
>   modes”, Unix tools such as tr can
>   convert between CRLF and LF endings,
>   but cygutils provides several
>   dedicated programs: conv, d2u,
>   dos2unix, u2d, and unix2dos. Use the
>   --help switch for usage information.

Answer (score 1):

The command `file` used like this

```
file file-to-check.txt
```

Will tell you what kind of line terminators are being used

I think cygwin has dos2unix and unix2dos

http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html